# Как получать значение инпута и класть в массив.React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет.как получить textContent,если я заполняю компонент мапом

```js
  const BranchComponent = ({data, cbClick,pickDoctor}) => {
    const handlerClick = () => {
       cbClick();
       pickDoctor(data);
    }
    return(
        <MDBCol md="4">
            <div className="branch">
                <input type="text" value={data.name}  onClick={handlerClick} readOnly/>
            </div>
        </MDBCol>
    )
  
  constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            activeStep: 0,
            date: null,
            values: []
        };
        this.addValueToArray = this.addValueToArray.bind(this);
    }


    addValueToArray(e) {
        const {textContent} = e.currentTarget;
        const {values} = this.state;
        if (values.indexOf(textContent) === -1) {
            this.setState({
                values: [...this.state.values, textContent]
            });
        }
    }
 
 return (
                    <>
                        <MDBRow>
                            {branchesData.map((data, index) => (
                                <BranchComponent
                                    data={data}
                                    key={index}
                                    pickDoctor={item => alert(item.name)}
                                    cbClick={this.addValueToArray}
                                />
                            ))}
                            <ul>
                                {this.state.values.map((value, index) => (
                                    <li key={index}>{value}</li>
                                ))}
                            </ul>
                        </MDBRow>
                    </>
                );
```

[image: Ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

В `handlerClick` функция `cbClick()` просто выполняется без параметров и, соответственно, переданная `addValueToArray` тоже просто выполняется без передачи параметров. Т.е. `e` всегда undefined и вызывает указанную вами ошибку. И `map` здесь ни причем